# How i can read app iPhone output on my mac app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, xcode, macos

Who knows how to write an application on a Mac that will receive a signal from the iPhone just like Xcode Output. For example, my iPhone is connected to my Mac and when I press the button in my application on the iPhone , in the button outlet says "print (" bla-bla-bla ")" and when I click on the button on the phone in my Xcode in Output the inscription pops up bla-bla-bla. And I need xcode output to be viewed through my Mac application. If anyone knows really looking forward to hear!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be useful to know what it is you are trying achieve by doing this. Printing output should only be for debugging purposes whilst developing an application.

If you are wanting to output information from an iPhone app to a Mac one then you could create a service that pushes messages to a queue and a Mac app that reads from that queue and displays them.